# Simple tensorflow operation runs forever but nothing happens

Tags: tensorflow

I am using Python 3.6.8 with a virtual environment on a Linux system. I installed tensorflow 2.2.0 via `pip3 install tensorflow`. When I try running a simple example (in a Jupyther notebook):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```

then the cell is running forever, but I never get an output. Sometimes the kernel dies. I noticed that I received the following errors in the terminal:

```
2020-06-03 07:33:58.865622: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 

E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-06-03 07:33:58.865690: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (rcnl101): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
```

That's why I tried to change my tensorflow to a version that only supports CPU via

```
pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

This did not solve the problem. Now I don't get all these messages anymore, but the cell is still running forever without giving me any output.

Does anyone have an idea??

Comment: Did you uninstall the `tensorflow` package before installing `tensorflow-cpu`? If you didn't, I'd uninstall all things TensorFlow and try from there (or try in a clean virtual environment). Did you follow the [GPU support guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) to install the CUDA libraries? Or, if you don't want to use the GPU, you can try to put `import os; os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'` _before_ `import tensorflow as tf`, although I'm not sure if it will fix it...

Comment: @Maria Reinhardt, Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the comment mentioned above ?

Comment: Hi , Can you please look at this thread , It seems to be a CUDA mismatch issue.                      https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24243#issuecomment-453060034